# How to delete the matching entries in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to delete an row from sqlite but my senario is when i first enter a text field it should be inserted to the table and when I again enter the text field with same value it should not be entered as second row,It should be deleting the first entry and get updated and table Id should remain 1 only.

I dont know how to do it,Please suggest me as I doing first time the database.

Thanks.

Table creation:

```
            "CREATE TABLE secure" + DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME_SETTINGS + " (" +
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_ID_SETTINGS+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_LASTNAME +" TEXT,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_PHONENUMBER +" TEXT,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_EMAILADDRESS +" TEXT,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_ADDRESSLINE1 +" TEXT,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_ADDRESSLINE2 +" TEXT,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_LOCALITY +" TEXT,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_CITY +" TEXT,"+
                    DatabaseContract.RetailDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_PINCODE +" TEXT" + 
                    ")";
```

Comment: What is TEXT_TYPE ?.. Better put the "TEXT_TYPE" outside the quotes

Comment: It is TEXT..I am having different class where I created all tables..........private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";

Comment: there is no space between table values and their types

Comment: means,I dont get it what u want to say.?

Comment: I have made some edits check them.

Comment: But when I try to use this type of table creation,it giving me syntax error..

Comment: I made another edit.. this might help.

Comment: Actually what now happenning is when I am inserting firstname row id is not incrementing but it is not updating I want that it should be update also..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `UNIQUE` constraint to the column of the table you want dont want to have duplicated values. like below

```
COLUMN_NAME+ " TEXT UNIQUE, "
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not as tough as you think. While you create your database, make the value uniique like:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE secure (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "name TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE," +
            "value TEXT" +
            ");");
```

NOw when you try to insert same "name" again and again in the above table, sqlite will automatically insert and replace for you. Thus no duplicate values.

Comment: like if I am having 4-5 columns in my table,and by making one column unique can I update the entire row,if I get duplicate text value?

Comment: I tried but it is not working,please check my creation of table..I am updating my question.